# Perfmon Unnstallation Advanced Installer

Tags: .net, perfmon, advanced-installer

I'm using advanced Installer to make a setup of my application based on .NET. I use the .NETInstallerClass custom action to install perfmon counters on the target computer. The target dlls(from where my counters are to be installed) are placed in a subfolder in my .aip file, but are set to be installed in the parent folder of this subfolder (Because I want different dlls with the same name to be installed on different conditions).
The application gets installed fine. I wish to use .NETInstallerClass custom action to uninstall the counters, but while setting the custom action, advanced installer forces me to set the path to the subfolder. So, Obviously at uninstall time, it cannot find the dlls as they are installed in the parent folder and the subfolder cannot be found.
Is there any workaround to this? I dont wish to write a script for perfmon uninstallation.

Comment: why does it forces you to use the assembly from the sub-folder. Can't you use the same assembly as you did to install perfmon?

Comment: at Install time I'm using the subfolder and it doesn't give me a problem, maybe because the perfmon are installed before the assemblies are copied from the subfolder to the parent (I'm guessing that's how advanced installer works).
but while uninstalling, the subfolder doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you send me an email with the project file and logs from the install and uninstall on bogdan at advancedinstaller.com? Its not clear to me exactly what is happening